# While trying to install RegCM I get configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables after executing ./configure

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc, configure

used

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

and got this

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... icc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/RegCM-master':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

The config log says the following:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by RegCM configure 4.9.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = jorgenava-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.8.0-38-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #43~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 12 16:39:47 UTC 2021

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2481: checking build system type
configure:2495: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2515: checking host system type
configure:2528: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2569: checking how to print strings
configure:2596: result: printf
configure:2668: checking for gcc
configure:2695: result: icc
configure:2924: checking for C compiler version
configure:2933: icc --version >&5
./configure: line 2935: icc: command not found
configure:2944: $? = 127
configure:2933: icc -v >&5
./configure: line 2935: icc: command not found
configure:2944: $? = 127
configure:2933: icc -V >&5
./configure: line 2935: icc: command not found
configure:2944: $? = 127
configure:2933: icc -qversion >&5
./configure: line 2935: icc: command not found
configure:2944: $? = 127
configure:2964: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2986: icc    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 2988: icc: command not found
configure:2990: $? = 127
configure:3028: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "RegCM"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "regcm"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.9.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "RegCM 4.9.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ggiulian@ictp.it"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3033: error: in `/home/jorgenava/Modelos_de_Simulacion/RegCM-master':
configure:3035: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=icc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FC_set=set
ac_cv_env_FC_value=ifort
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_MPIFC_set=set
ac_cv_env_MPIFC_value=mpiifort
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=icc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEPFLAGS=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR=''
AM_BACKSLASH=''
AM_CPPFLAGS=''
AM_DEFAULT_V=''
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
AM_LDFLAGS=''
AM_V=''
AR=''
AUTOCONF=''
AUTOHEADER=''
AUTOMAKE=''
AWK=''
CC='icc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
COMPILER_CRAY_FALSE=''
COMPILER_CRAY_TRUE=''
COMPILER_G95_FALSE=''
COMPILER_G95_TRUE=''
COMPILER_GNU_FALSE=''
COMPILER_GNU_TRUE=''
COMPILER_IBM_FALSE=''
COMPILER_IBM_TRUE=''
COMPILER_INTEL_FALSE=''
COMPILER_INTEL_TRUE=''
COMPILER_PGI_FALSE=''
COMPILER_PGI_TRUE=''
COMPILER_SUN_FALSE=''
COMPILER_SUN_TRUE=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPRDEF=''
CYGPATH_W=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DO_COMPILE_CPL_FALSE=''
DO_COMPILE_CPL_TRUE=''
DO_COMPILE_LIBCLM45_FALSE=''
DO_COMPILE_LIBCLM45_TRUE=''
DO_COMPILE_LIBCLM_FALSE=''
DO_COMPILE_LIBCLM_TRUE=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F90FLAGS=''
FC='ifort'
FCFLAGS=''
FCPROG=''
FGREP=''
FORT_SIZE=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAKEINFO=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P=''
MPEUCFLAGS=''
MPEUFCFLAGS=''
MPIFC='mpiifort'
MPILIBS=''
NC_INCLUDES=''
NC_LDFLAGS=''
NC_LIBS=''
NC_PREFIX=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
NOOPTFC=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OMPFLAGS=''
OSNAME=''
OSNAME_AIX_FALSE=''
OSNAME_AIX_TRUE=''
OSNAME_LINUX_FALSE=''
OSNAME_LINUX_TRUE=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='ggiulian@ictp.it'
PACKAGE_NAME='RegCM'
PACKAGE_STRING='RegCM 4.9.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='regcm'
PACKAGE_URL='https://gforge.ictp.it/gf/project/regcm'
PACKAGE_VERSION='4.9.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
REGCM_PARALLEL_FALSE=''
REGCM_PARALLEL_TRUE=''
REGCM_ROOT=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
SYSLIBS=''
VERSION=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='icc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_ct_FC=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot=''
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar=''
am__untar=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "RegCM"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "regcm"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.9.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "RegCM 4.9.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "ggiulian@ictp.it"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

my system is ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It looks like you don't have a C compiler installed on the system (neither `gcc` nor `icc`)

Comment: Hint, RegCM https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359693/error-in-running-the-make-command-in-installing-regcm/1359740#1359740

Comment: @KnudLarsen it worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to the solution is to install the `build-essential` meta-package.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Comment: Already installed it but the problem continued